# ocfs2_dlmfs file system not found while running tunefs.ocf2s command

Tags: debian, filesystems, ocfs2

While running the following [tunefs](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tunefs(8)) command to enable the `discontig-bg` file system feature:

```
tunefs.ocfs2 --fs-features=discontig-bg /dev/drbd0
```

I receive the following error:

```
tunefs.ocfs2: ocfs2_dlmfs file system was not found while opening device "/dev/drbd0"
```

When running `mount` I don't see the `ocfs2_dlmfs` mount as expected, only the `/dev/drbd0`.

---

We did upgrade the kernel from `4.19.0-25-amd64` to `5.10`, after which we encountered the error. Unfortunately downgrading to `4.19` did not resolve the issue. We're not even sure if the kernel version is related.

---

###### System information:

Operating system: Debian 10 (buster)
Kernel version: `4.19.0-25-amd64`
TuneFS version: `tunefs.ocfs2 1.8.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, first run

```
dpkg-reconfigure ocfs2-tools
```

Where you get the following option:

> ```
> Would you like to start an OCFS2 cluster (O2CB) at boot time?
> ```

When you answer this with `Yes`, the dlmfs mount will persist and my original

```
tunefs.ocfs2 --fs-features=discontig-bg /dev/drbd0
```

command completes without any errors.